A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. What should I do?
I'm trying to connect my react app to my fastapi app and enable authentication but I keep having this error: "A  is only ever to be used as the child of  element, never rendered directly".
In my **app.js**, I have the following function:
const AllRoutes = () => {
  const Auth = React.useContext(AuthApi);
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}/>
      
      <Route path="/login" element={<ProtectedLogin auth={Auth.auth} component={Login} />}/>
      <Route path="/" element={<ProtectedRoute auth={Auth.auth} component={Home} />}/>
    </Routes>
  );
};

This is my **ProtectedLogin**:
const ProtectedLogin = ({ auth, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() => (!auth ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/" />)}
    />
  );
};

This is my **ProtectedRoute**:
const ProtectedRoute = ({ auth, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() => (auth ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/login" />)}
    />
  );
};

When I change the **ProtectedRoute** and **ProtectedLogin** to:
const ProtectedRoute = ({ auth, component: Component}) => {
  return auth ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

const ProtectedLogin = ({ auth, component: Component}) => {
  return auth ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

Only the Register page works. When I click Login or Home, It just hangs up on me. Please help!! Thank you.
